# HP Dl360e Gen8 Not Detecting Hard Drives

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a new HP Proliant DL360e G8 and it is not detecting the hard drives.

We are using both non-hp, and official hp hard drives from an older server (DL120). Hard drives are 3.5" and they are not being detected by the raid controller (HP B320i).

I have tried with the caddies and without and both times the same results.

They are no errors on the POST and the raid controller is getting detected.

EDIT:
Found the fix. Hard-drives did not work. Found you need SATA 3 6GB/s 64MB hard-drives (WD20EZRX).
Server is now working on VMWare ESXI with no faults or issues.

Comment: **The hard drives are not being detected by...?** The RAID controller? The Operating System? Are you getting lights and power activity on the drives?

Comment: We have lights (orange) on the front of the caddies, raid controller is being detected, no OS just HP smart storage, to view the hard-drives and create an array.

Comment: Interesting. What are the makes/models of the disks?

Comment: Western Digital - WD20EURS / Western Digital - WD5003ABYX

Comment: The first drive is probably compatible. The second drive may not work on the controller.

Comment: Can you recommend any hard-drives that work? We need 2TB 3.5" hard-drives.

Comment: Sure: HP's 2TB nearline SAS disk (**652757-B21**) or HP's 2TB SATA disk (**658079-B21**).

Comment: Found the issue. You need SATA 3 6GB/s 64MB hard-drive.